# SQL - subquery count

Tags: sql, count, subquery

I have started the following code

```
SELECT distinct crq_risk 
    ,count(crq_risk) as 'count'
    ,(  select count(datediff(day,submit_date,crq_scheduled_for_approval_date)) 
        from change_information
        where crq_risk = 'Risk Level 1'
            and submit_date >= '2016-05-01 00:00:00.000'
            and crq_scheduled_for_approval_date IS NOT NULL
            and crq_change_timing = 'Non Standard - Planned'
            and datediff (day,submit_date,crq_scheduled_for_approval_date) < 10) as RL1
   ,(   select count(datediff(day,submit_date,crq_scheduled_for_approval_date)) 
        from change_information
        where crq_risk = 'Risk Level 2'
            and submit_date >= '2016-05-01 00:00:00.000'
            and crq_scheduled_for_approval_date IS NOT NULL
            and crq_change_timing = 'Non Standard - Planned'
            and datediff (day,submit_date,crq_scheduled_for_approval_date) < 10) as RL2
    ,(  select count(datediff(day,submit_date,crq_scheduled_for_approval_date)) 
        from change_information
        where crq_risk = 'Risk Level 3'
            and submit_date >= '2016-05-01 00:00:00.000'
            and crq_scheduled_for_approval_date IS NOT NULL
            and crq_change_timing = 'Non Standard - Planned'
            and datediff (day,submit_date,crq_scheduled_for_approval_date) < 5) as RL3
   ,(   select count(datediff(day,submit_date,crq_scheduled_for_approval_date)) 
        from change_information
        where crq_risk = 'Risk Level 4'
            and submit_date >= '2016-05-01 00:00:00.000'
            and crq_scheduled_for_approval_date IS NOT NULL
            and crq_change_timing = 'Non Standard - Planned'
            and datediff (day,submit_date,crq_scheduled_for_approval_date) < 3) as RL4
from change_information
where submit_date >= '2016-05-01 00:00:00.000'
    and crq_scheduled_for_approval_date IS NOT NULL
    and crq_change_timing = 'Non Standard - Planned'
group by crq_risk
```

This results in

```
crq_risk        count   RL1   RL2   RL3  RL4
Risk Level 1    0       0.00  7     69   101
Risk Level 2    8       0.00  7     69   101
Risk Level 3    183     0.00  7     69   101
Risk Level 4    247     0.00  7     69   101

whereas I want the table to look like this 

crq_risk       count  edited_count
Risk Level 1   0      0
Risk Level 2   8      7
Risk Level 3   183    69
Risk Level 4   247    101
```

Comment: Always tag the DBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, MS Access...) you are using as each dialect will vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sum()` with `case statement`

```
SELECT distinct crq_risk 
    ,count(crq_risk) as 'count'
    ,sum( case when ((crq_risk in ('Risk Level 1', 'Risk Level 2') and datediff (day,submit_date,crq_scheduled_for_approval_date) < 10)
                    or (crq_risk = 'Risk Level 3' and datediff (day,submit_date,crq_scheduled_for_approval_date) < 5)
                    or (crq_risk = 'Risk Level 4' and datediff (day,submit_date,crq_scheduled_for_approval_date) < 3))
            then 1 else 0 end 
        ) as edited_count
from change_information
where submit_date >= '2016-05-01 00:00:00.000'
    and crq_scheduled_for_approval_date IS NOT NULL
    and crq_change_timing = 'Non Standard - Planned'
group by crq_risk;
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. But this is sum is group by `crq_risk` so `edited_count` will be different for  `Risk Level 1` and `2`. And it's `case statement` not `count`. Tested and worked :)